# Is it possible to link different map's cursors in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

Is it possible to link different map's cursors in Google Earth Engine?

For exemple:

```
var left = ui.Map();
var leftcusor = left.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair')

var right = ui.Map();
var rightcursor = right.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair')

ui.root.clear();
ui.root.add(left);
ui.root.add(right);


ui.Map.Linker([left, right])
```

How can leftcursor and rightcursor move together (like in Erdas) ?

Comment: I think this come closest: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8698ef5e0325a8e970a56c6c75900719  If you want pixel information of different maps, just add them as multiple layers or single image with multiple bands to the map.

Comment: I know this script and methods. Budt I would like to see the crosshairs on different compistes in the same time.